# PHP Array to string conversion error when param is known string

Tags: php, mariadb

I'm really stumped with this error.  I have read many other posts on SO about this error but none of them seem to address my problem.  I have done several tests and they all show the value as a string.  I'll post the entire code in hopes of getting some help.

> **Error Message:** Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/u645944288/public_html/Scripts/PHP/Class/TEST/Board.class.php on
>   line 48

Array

**Class Code:**

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

Class Board {

    public $Connect;
    public $Poster;
    public $PostTo;
    public $Post;
    public $PostedDate;
    public $Poster2;
    public $PostTo2;
    public $Post2;
    public $Rows;

    public function __construct($PostToID) {
        try {
            $this->Connect = new pdo("mysql:host=wwwww;dbname=xxxxx", "yyyyy", "zzzzz");
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            die(json_encode(array('outcome' => false, 'message' => 'Unable to connect')));
        }
        $query = $this->Connect->prepare("SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE ID = :ID");
        $query->bindValue(":ID", $PostToID);
        $query->execute() or die($query->ErrorInfo());
        $Row = $query->fetch();
        $this->PostTo = $Row['Username'];
    }

    public function DisplayPosts() {
        $query = $this->Connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE Username = :Username");
        $query->bindParam(':Username', $this->PostTo);
        if (is_array($this->PostTo)) {
            echo('$this->PostTo is an array<br>' . PHP_EOL);
        } else {
            echo('$this->PostTo is NOT an array<br>' . PHP_EOL);
        }
        var_dump($this->PostTo);
        echo('<br>' . PHP_EOL);
        echo('Before $query->execute() - Username: ' . $this->PostTo . '<br>' . PHP_EOL);
        $query->execute() or die($query->ErrorInfo());
        echo('After $query->execute()<br>' . PHP_EOL);
        $this->Rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($this->Rows as $data) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                echo("key: $key - value: $value<br>" . PHP_EOL);
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

**Results of is_array and var_dump()**

`$this->PostTo` is NOT an array

```
string(9) "Masonh928"
```

Before $query->execute() - Username: Masonh928

Line 48 is: `$query->execute() or die($query->ErrorInfo());`, it is between the Before and After echo commands.  The script stops at this point so the After echo is never shown.

Can anyone help me see what i have done wrong?

Thanks for any and all help,

Charles

Comment: PDO `errorInfo()` method returns an array, not a string..... this is more likely your problem triggering the error

Comment: @ Mark Baker Well, I'll be a monkeys uncle.  You were correct.  I removed the or die part and the code now runs.  Thank you very much.  If you post an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @CharlesEF.. if it was hitting the `or die()` part then your code query is not being run, unless you fixed whatever the error was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like someone mentioned in the comments, the string conversion is coming from the error. Your query is failing and trying to convert the error array to a string. Try this.

```
$query->execute() or die(print_r($query->ErrorInfo()));
```

2 things that may help:

I don't know if "Posts" or "Username" is a reserved word or not, but it's good practice to use backticks on your table and column names:

```
"SELECT * FROM `Posts` WHERE `Username` = :Username"
```

Also, you'll get better error messages if you put this line abouve your query somewhere.

```
$this->Connect->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
```

Comment: Yes,  Mark Baker and you are correct.  I also found the reason I had that problem with the 'or die(...)' part.  Seems I forgot to create the table on my hosting site.  It worked on my localhost but failed when uploaded to my site.  Problem now fixed.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: @CharlesEF Awesome, if that solved your problem please hit the checkmark by the answer to claim your points..